# Why are there not $3^3 \over 3!$ ways to select $3$ elements from different sets, not caring about order?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Say there are three sets of cardinality 3 where each set has no element in common with the other 2. When I think of the number of combinations of 3 items where each item is from a different one of these three sets, I am seeing that this is $3^3 \over 3!$, but this isn't an integer. I am seeing this because if I think of the number of permutations, this is $3^3$ as there are $3$ choices for each element we select, and each combination is represented $3!$ times in the set of all permutations, as there are $3!$ ways to order it, so we divide the number of permutations by $3!$ to get the number of combinations. Conceptually, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Each set has no element in common with the $2$ others, so there is only $1$ permutation. I.e. you do not have to divide by $3!$

Comment: Have you written the $3^3$ combinations down? Why do you claim each combination is represented $3!$ times? Can you point out *concretely* 6 combinations that are the same?

Answer (score 1):

We are choosing one element from each of the 3 disjoint sets. So, by product rule, the total possible combinations are `3*3*3` . But as they are disjoint sets , no combination occurs more than once because there are no common elements .
But the number of permutations is equal to `3*3*3*3!` as we can arrange each combination in `3!` ways.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a concrete example.  Define the three sets as:

$$S_1 = \{ a, b, c \}$$
$$S_2 = \{ d, e, f \}$$
$$S_3 = \{ g, h, i \}$$

A simple brute-force enumeration gives us 27 distinct ways to select one value from each set: adg, adh, adi, aeg, aeh, aei, afg, afh, afi, bdg, bdh, bdi, beg, beh, bei, bfg, bfh, bfi, cdg, cdh, cdi, ceg, ceh, cei, cfg, cfh, and cfi.

The important point here is that all of the combinations are distinct.  For example, `adg` is allowed, but not `agd`, `dag`, `dga`, `gad`, or `gda`.  This is because `a` is *only* in $S_1$, `d` is *only* in $S_2$, and `g` is *only* in $S_3$.  Since you don't have any duplicates to filter out, the answer is just $3^3 = 27$, without the division.

---

You may be wondering about the case where the sets *do* have the same elements.

$$S_1 = S_2 = S_3 = \{ a, b, c \}$$

This time, we still have 27 permutations: aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc, baa, bab, bac, bba, bbb, bbc, bca, bcb, bcc, caa, cab, cac, cba, cbb, cbc, cca, ccb, and ccc.  But the number of combinations (ignoring order) is 10: aaa, aab, aac, abb, abc, acc, bbb, bbc, bcc, and ccc.

So, why do we *not* get $\frac{3^3}{3!} = 4.5$?  Because not all combinations are repeated $3! = 6$ times.  Only `abc` occurs 6 times (as `abc`, `acb`, `bac`, `bca`, `cab`, and `cba`.  But `aab` occurs only 3 times (`aab`, `aba`, and `baa`), as do the other combinations with two copies of one element (`aac`, `abb`, `acc`, `bbc`, and `bcc`).  And the three combinations with one element (`aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc`) only occur once.